# rewrite headers in outgoing mail for forwarded mail

Tags: centos7, plesk

**System**
I'm using Centos7 with Plesk Obsidian with Postfix

**What do I want to achieve;**
When a mail is send from x@domain1.com to y@domain2.com it is forwarded to z@domain3.com

The sender is x@domain1.com when it is send.
I need the sender to be y@domain2.com when it arrives a z@domain3.com

For security reasons the mail needs to come from confirmed addresses, that's why I always need the sender to be the address from which the mail is forwarded.

What I tried is adjusting the mail.cf file without any succes.